# NDMP to VTL on a second SAN (with copy to physical)

Tags: backup, storage-area-network, tape, virtualization, library

I've got a Sun Storage 7000 that I'd like to backup/restore via the built-in NDMP service, since we've got an secondary SAN attached which is available via two 10GbE links to the primary storage I'd like to deploy it as a VTL solution. The secondary storage could easily be expanded with a SCSI HBA connected to a (small) 28 slot library providing two LTO4 drives. It seems that currently no FOSS backup app is able to be used as a NDMP VTL (with copy to physical tape) solution. Any low cost solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [ndmpjob](http://traakan.com/ndmjob/).  I have no direct experience with it but it looks like it does everything you'd want with NDMP.

And it's free, source included.

Comment: `ndmpjob`seems to be _way_ to basic for what I'd like to do. Just because I said it should be a low cost solution doesn't mean that I'm not ready to spend a few bucks here and there.

Comment: Well, a little script-foo here and there would make it usable.  My direct experience is with netbackup, and that'll run you a bit more than free + time spent on scripting/testing.  I'm not sure if there are any "low-cost" ndmp, only big $$$ and free.